# PHP Slug Generation Function Giving Improper Output

Tags: php, php-5.3, slug

I am using below code to get a proper slug that I am sending from an ajax call.

```
$slug = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]+/', '-', $_POST['slug'])));
```

But, what's happening is. If from an ajax request I am getting any slug-like

slug: `top-5-ways--to-avoid-list-`

I want to trim unwanted `-` hyphens and any numeric values from the slug and want the below slug

slug: `top-ways-to-avoid-list`

I am not able to understand that what is wrong with the code.

Comment: And what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slugify your string this way, it'll remove unwanted characters including `-`.

[trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) takes as 2nd parameter **all characters that you want to be stripped**. So have a look on the commented line `THIS WILL FIX YOUR EXISTING PROBLEM`

```
<?php
function slugify($string, $delimiter = '-'){
  $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\/_|+ -]/", '', $string); 
  $clean = strtolower($clean);
  $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
  $clean = trim($clean, $delimiter); // THIS WILL FIX YOUR EXISTING PROBLEM
  return $clean;
}

echo slugify('-Top ways-to avoid list-');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo slugify('top 5 ways to get in top');
?>
```

**Output:**

```
top-ways-to-avoid-list 
top-ways-to-get-in-top
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/ljtlZ

**OR** with your existing code trimming multiple characters `-` or spaces

```
<?php
echo strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]+/', '-', '-Top ways-to avoid list-'),'- '));
echo PHP_EOL;
echo strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]+/', '-', 'top 5 ways to get in top'),'- '));
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/aBtHI

Comment: i also want to eliminate any numeric values from the string, if i input `top 5 ways to get in top` it gives me `top-5-ways-to-get-in-top`

Comment: the code works perfectly but can't we use it more efficiently like the above answer which is posted with this, it's only two lines and works perfectly. As we are using this function it might impact in milliseconds as per processing

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav have a look again on the answer. I've used your existing code to fix the issue by using trimming **multiple** characters at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can trim again to remove extra '-' from both side of the string.

```
   $slug = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]+/', '-', 'top-5-ways--to-avoid-list-')));
    echo trim($slug, '-');
```

Result: **top-ways-to-avoid-list**